# Why didn't Fuuko's unluck power work on Andy, when he was having his alternate personality of Victor?

Tags: undead-unluck

After Andy turned Victor, Fuuko touched him, and his unluck power didn't work.

Why didn't it work?

Comment: It was stated you needed to care about the person for the Unluck to trigger. The greater the love for the person, greater the resulting unluck